# update_dyld_sim_shared_cache is taking up a lot of memory

Tags: macos, memory, big-sur

I just noticed that `update_dyld_sim_shared_cache` is taking up `5.5GB` of memory. It is significantly slowing down my MacBook. Would it be safe to force quit this?

I am using macOS Big Sur Version 11.1

[image]

Comment: How does the memory pressure chart at the bottom of the window look like?

Comment: @nohillside `swap_used` was at `7GB` which is the highest I have ever seen on my laptop and the chart was yellow in color instead of green. But the process just stopped on its own and now its back to normal. Still no idea why this happened.

Comment: Have you run any updates recently? That process rebuilds the system kernel cache after updates & you really should let it finish.

Comment: @Tetsujin updates to any apps or to macOS? If you mean the latter then no.

Comment: I would definitely expect it after system updates, not certain about app updates. It's how the system keeps track of library files & their locations which it builds into a list it can quickly access. It's "go-faster stripes" for the OS.

Comment: @Tetsujin so I checked under `Installations` and `XProtectPlistConfigData:` was just installed from `Apple` any idea what it is?

Comment: XProtect is part of Apple's built-in malware detector suite - https://www.howtogeek.com/217043/xprotect-explained-how-your-macs-built-in-anti-malware-works/

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks that explains everything

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This specific program is used to update a separate dynamic linking cache for the Simulator app that comes with Xcode. It runs to update the cache at times such as for example after updating Xcode and after installing new iPhone/iPad/iOS/iPadOS models/versions in the simulator.

Normally it should run to completion within a reasonable time, and then go away until the next update.

If it keeps running for hours and hours, it is safe to stop the process. The cache will be updated automatically later as necessary.